# Possible to revoke default ability for all future users to connect to *any* database?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, access-control

I have a lab with a database that I would like to use as a "multi-tenant" database, in that I would like to create a database for each of the applications that I'm running and segregate access so that user foo and user bar cannot see anything about their neighbors. I'm somewhat surprised to discover that any new user, **by default**, has the ability to list databases, connect to them, and list their tables.

My understanding is that this ability is inherited from the public role (could use confirmation of this)? I can think of two potential options, one being more desirable:

- I know I can revoke CONNECT from an explicit database, but this requires that I specify the database. I want to revoke this for all current, **and future** databases as the default privilege.
- I could potentially create users with the NOINHERIT attribute (assuming this ability is inherited from public), but I don't think that's ideal because a new user could easily be created without this, and it would have access.

Is this not something to be concerned about because even if a user connects to a database, they can't really do anything inside of it?